# SSAS: why aren't FK relationships shown with named query?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ssas, business-intelligence, sql-server-data-tools

I have two fact tables: `FactSales` & `FactInvoices`. Both have an foreign key relationship with `DimDate.Datekey`. In VS, the SSAS DSV displays these relationships (the lines are drawn between the tables).

In the DSV I decided to to create a named query that limits the `dimdate` to 2021. After doing this, I still see the relationships between the two fact tables and dimdate (which is now a *named query*).

At the DB-level, I created a 3rd fact table called `FactExpenses`. `FactExpenses` also has an FK relationship with `DimDate.Datekey`. The problem is that my dsv (in SSAS) does not recognize this relationship (ie. It doesn't draw the line between both tables).

Two questions: why doesn't VS display the relationship between my 3rd fact table with the named query but it does with the other two fact tables? I understand that the relationship isn't with the named query, but the relationship should disappear in all the fact tables.

When I want to limit the amount of data displayed in dimdate, should I use a named query?

Answer (score 0):

The relationships in the DSV are separate to the foreign keys on the base tables, but they get added automatically based on the database schema when you add tables to the DSV. My guess would be when you added the initial dim and fact tables to the DSV in Visual Studio it automatically added the relationships based on the foreign keys that exist on the base tables, but this may not occur automatically for named queries. You can [manually add the relationship yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/define-logical-relationships-in-a-data-source-view-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions#bkmk_addRel) for the third table to get the same result.

I think a named query is a reasonable approach for the filtering you want to do. An alternative would be to create a view in the source database if you need to do more intense or complex filtering.